# AWS Amplify/Lambda/ApiGateway - CORS headers in F12 Network tab does not equal API Gateway Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have a site on AWS Amplify that is making an API call to an API Gateway Lambda integration. After strugglebussing with CORS errors for quite a while, I got it working but my headers arent what I expect.

**Below is my API gatweway config**: I have two allow-origin values and only GET, POST, OPTIONS methods being allowed.
[image: API Gateway CORS settings]

After applying these settings, when I look in the browser f12 network panel when running these API calls through the website, I see that the **access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods,** and **access-control-allow-origin** are set to values that I have not assigned in my config:
[image: CORS Response Headers]

So on to the question - ***Are the response header results normal?*** I expected to see the headers and http methods I allowed/exposed in the browser api calls and I'm seeing completely different values. I dont know if this is normal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check your code if you are not exposing all methods in CORS. e.g. if it is on node js / express then below snippet can cause that problem. you can always limit those controls here. If I'm not wrong then your code overrides your gateway configurations.

```
// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});
```